# Is it possible to have clickable class names in console output in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

When you run a server inside of IntelliJ you can see the console output in the window at the bottom of the screen.

Is there any way to format the output so that IntelliJ will recognize class names and make them clickable? Then when I see a class name in the server output I could click on it and go straight there.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is. Taken from online help http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/setting-log-options.html

> If you are using third-party logging tools, you might want to make the
>   message's output, that mimics a standard linkage to the source code as
>   for stacktrace line (at
>   .(:)).
>   For that, you should add specific Conversion Pattern to your log.xml
>   configuration file. For example, in a log4j Conversion Pattern this
>   would be

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - [%-80m] - at %c.%M(%F:%L)%n"/>
```

However the produces output is quite ugly with fully qualified names, method names etc.

Comment: The official documentation is rather vague on what is needed as a minimum (which would be relevant here)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/setting-log-options.html

Comment: I've found this pattern helpful for local Spring development (based on a pared-down version of the default Spring logging pattern): `%clr(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(%-45.45(\(%F:%L\)){44}){magenta} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%wEx}`

Answer (score 35):

As of IntelliJ 14 and alternative to digging through IntelliJ settings, some trial and error revealed that anything with the pattern

```
(anyfile.ext:line)
```

preceded by at least one `.` in the console gets turned into a file link if there any file known by that name, e.g. `.(Whatever.java:55)`, in the workspace excluding those of libraries.

I am using logback. So at a minimum in my logback.xml to get links to my classes I included in my message pattern

```
.\(%class{0}.java:%line\)
```

- `.\(    \)` -> A dot must precede the filename:line pattern and the filename:line pattern enclosed in parentheses. Logback requires literal parentheses to be escaped in this case.
- `%class{0}` -> Just the classname without a package
- `.java` -> So that it matches the complete filename
- `:%line` -> Is the logging line of code

In actuality, I have other things which always includes at least one `.` before the `(filename:line)` portion, so it is being picked up by IntelliJ just as well.

```
<pattern>%highlight(%-5level) %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} %yellow([%thread]) %blue(%logger{36}\(%class{0}.java:%line\)) %msg%n</pattern>
```

Comment: With this you get only clickable links for your own classes, I prefer adding %caller{1} at the end of the pattern to be able to click on any class.

Comment: Note to self: Logback has %file which will work more naturally for files not ending in .java (i.e. .kt for kotlin). Replaced `%blue(%logger{36}\(%class{0}.java:%line\))` with `%blue(%logger{36}\(%file:%line\))`

Comment: `%file` also works better for inner classes and lambdas.

Comment: It seems the preceding `.` is not needed, at least in Android Studio 3.0 and so possibly in similar versions of IntelliJ.

Comment: Caveat: The pattern \(.*\) should not appear _before_ the mention of this link, else the link will not be set. Furthermore, if the pattern at\s appears after such a link, the link will not be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Install the IntelliJ Plugin Awesome Console from Marketplace: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7677-awesome-console

Then everything in your terminal including maven build failures for Java classes is also clickable.

Answer (score 0):

To make things REALLY work you need to comply with the full stacktrace notation. Like its NOT enough to simply put a dot "." in front of the brackets. If you have two classes with same name but different packages, IntelliJ will choose the first it finds. In order to get this working CORRECTLY even in this case you need to write

fullyqualifiedclassname + "." + methodname + "(" + simpleclassname + ".java:" + linenumber + ")"

If you dont know the line number using ":1" worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To complete @JasonDunkelberger's answer, after errors and trials, I got a better regular exception that Intellij is probably parsing to find where to place hyperlinks:

```
(at )?+.*\..*\(.*?\)
```

In @JasonDunkelberger's answer, in some cases if there were some parentheses after the link, or the two letters 'at', the link would not activate.

Answer (score 0):

after some trials, i got a workable setting in spring boot project, with Intellig IDEA ULIMATE 2017.3.2 and logback 1.2.3
settings in **logback-spring.xml** like this:

```
<configuration>
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(at %class.%method){cyan} \\(%file:%line\\) %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

**%clr(at %class.%method){cyan} \(%file:%line\)**
is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Per the official doc, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html

I set it as below (I am using logback):

`<Pattern>%d %-5level - at %class.%M\(%file:%line\) - %msg %replace(%ex){'[\r\n]+', ''}%nopex%n</Pattern>`

Kind of hacky, but it works.

**Example log output:**

`2020-03-02 19:42:36,636 INFO  -     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) - FrameworkServlet 'bea': initialization started 
2020-03-02 19:42:36,779 INFO  -     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:581) - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'bea-servlet': startup date [Mon Mar 02 19:42:36 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy`

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to mention with using the **Log4j2/Logback conversion** patterns (`%class`, `%M`, etc.) is that it evaluates this during runtime from the Stacktrace which leads to **very high performance loss**. To address this **I developed a maven plugin** which can **inject information like caller method, class and even source code line number** into every SLF4J log statement call (log.info(), warn(),...) with nearly no performance loss:

[PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin](https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

pattern like:

`fullfileLoction :10`  is also ok.

for example:

For mac os

> /Users/myname/myjava/myproject/src/main/com/.../Main.java :10