# How to print file path as a hyperlink

Tags: java

I am printing logs of java program in the Intellij console and need to change file path from simple string to hyperlink so that I can click on that and it will openparticular file.

Is this something possible to do? Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have clickable class names in console output in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930844/is-it-possible-to-have-clickable-class-names-in-console-output-in-intellij)

Comment: Have you tried the following? `File f = new File(path); URL url = f.toURI().toURL(); // ..`

Answer (score 0):

Use below format while printing in console:

```
(anyfile.ext:line)
```

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29881239/2147481