# How to output variables to the console in Java (Intellij) that are clickable and send you to the line of code they are from

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console

I was programming in Intellij and noticed one of my variables was clickable. Not sure how I got it to do that, but then it got me thinking how awesome it would be if that actually took me to the line of code it came from when clicked.

So, my question is, what made my code do this, and is there any way to expand on it. Like, being able to output a clickable variable and after clicking it in the console it takes you to that exact line of code. Exactly like the stacktrace does when you have an error in your code. Also, is this even worth the effort, as in are there other methods that might achieve something similar.

I tried googling it but my terminology must be lacking because I wasn't able to find much. Any links to resources I can get more info would be great!

Here is the code that made my variable clickable: (I don't think this is a situation that requires an MRE so I've just included the specific method that outputs the clickable variable) Thank you!

```
    protected void updateSpritePositionAfterResizeOrEntrance(){
        Component cell = ui.jp.getComponentsInLayer(1)[compNum];
        //It will output a clickable "x: 368 y" 
        System.out.println("compNum: " + compNum + " x: " + cell.getX() + " y: " + cell.getY());

        int changeInWidth = cell.getX() + (cell.getWidth() / 2) - 16 - getX();
        int changeInHeight = cell.getY() + cell.getHeight() - 32 - getY();
        sprite.setLocation(changeInWidth, changeInHeight);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a plugin named `awesome console`.

> With this plugin all files and links in the console will be highlighted and can be clicked. Source code files will be opened in the IDE, other links with the default viewer/browser for this type. Now you just need to configure your favorite Logger to include the file name (and optionally a line number) and you can instantly jump to that file that throws this stupid error.

Here is the [link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7677-awesome-console) to get more info.

Comment: Looking back on this with more experience, I clearly was incorrect about what I thought was occurring. "Noticed one of the variables was clickable" was incorrect. No variable were clickable. What I had done was printed a string that contained syntax that IntelliJ's terminal identifies as a link. A link that when clicked takes you to the line of code that printed it. I found this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930844/is-it-possible-to-have-clickable-class-names-in-console-output-in-intellij) which explains this in more detail.