# Log4j2 wanna log the file&line number of caller

Tags: java, log4j2

I got the way to log the file path and line number from [Is it possible to have clickable class names in console output in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930844/is-it-possible-to-have-clickable-class-names-in-console-output-in-intellij)

But for some reason I have to do call the logging related method in a wrapped class (the reason is that I am bridging some self developped logging framework to log4j2):

```java
public class ILogAdapter extends CommonLogger {
    @Override
    public void info(String title, Throwable throwable) {
        // this.logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(key);
        logger.info(title, throwable);
    }
```

now when I do the log, the top method of callstack and file and line number always in this method, can I someway change this behavior?

update:

anyway I got a way to get the file/linenumber of the caller, and put it in the mdc context:

```java
    private void getLineAndFileOfCaller() {
        ThreadContext.clearAll();
        try {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = ex.getStackTrace();
            if(stackTrace.length > 3) {
                final StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = stackTrace[stackTrace.length - 3];
                ThreadContext.put("file" , Objects.toString(stackTraceElement.getFileName()));
                ThreadContext.put("line", Objects.toString(stackTraceElement.getLineNumber()));
            }
        }
    }
```

then I change my bridge method to:

```java
    @Override
    public void debug(String title, String message) {
        getLineAndFileOfCaller();
        logger.debug(String.format("[%s] %s", title, message));
    }
```

and set the log pattern to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <!--<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>-->
            <!--<PatternLayout pattern="%-5p - [%-80m] - at %c.%M(%F:%L)%n"/>-->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%(X{file}:%X{line}): %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

when I calling something like

```java
ILogAdapter#debug(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

I can get the file and linenumber of where i logged, but not the file and linenumber of the adapter in console.

I dont know if it's any better solution yet.

Comment: Please also provide example of current and expected log message for easier understanding.

Comment: @samabcde yeah I updated the qustion and provided maybe a work arround solution I found.